# How to set Format for DateTimePicker DatePart WPf

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed

I am using `Xceed` WPF Tool kit `DateTimePicker` control. I would like to set format for Time part in that control. Please find the attached image for your reference. In that image I would like set format for highlighted part only.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify that the format is `Custom`. Once you do that, then you can provide your actual custom format string, which the control will use to format the date for display. Here's a simple example in XAML:

```
<xctk:DateTimePicker Format="Custom"
                     FormatString="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
                     TimeFormat="Custom"
                     TimeFormatString="HH:mm" />
```

Comment: My system long time format is set to  "h m s t". But it is not working

Comment: Can you post the actual XAML for your control in the question? It would help to understand everything you're setting

Comment: <Ext:DateTimePicker Format="Custom" FormatString="dd MMMMM yyyy HH:mm" Value="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"
                                x:Name="d1" TimeFormat="Custom" TimeFormatString="HH:mm" CurrentDateTimePart="TimeZone"/>

Comment: This is the code i am using in xaml. If change system long time format to h m s t. The time part control format has been changed to HH mm. but required format is HH:mm

Answer (score 1):

xml

```
<wpfTool:DateTimePicker x:Name="beginDateTimePicker"/>
```

code

```
public void Init() {
        beginDateTimePicker.Format = Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.DateTimeFormat.Custom;
        beginDateTimePicker.FormatString = "HH:mm  dd.MM.yyyy";
        beginDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks